# Unable to update DB using Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to insert a new record into `tblUser` and also update a record in `tblEmployee` at the same time. The new record in tblUser saves fine, but the update part of second table is not working.
The complier reads `tbEmp.IsUser = true;` this line though. What am I missing.

```
public void Save(tblUser objUser)
{
    MYDB.AddTotblUsers(objUser);

    tblEmployee tbEmp = this.GetEmployeeRecordById(objUser.EmpId);
    if(tbEmp!=null)
      {
       string abc = tbEmp.EmployeeCode;
       tbEmp.IsUser = true;
      }
    MYDB.SaveChanges(); 
}

public tblEmployee GetEmployeeRecordById(Guid gId)
 {
    return MYDB.tblEmployees.Where(e=>e.EmployeeId == gId).SingleOrDefault();
 }
```

The EmpId is known already and is not necessary that tblUser has to Save First before updating tblEmployee. To make sure, I checked 'abc', I get that employees code there...

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you call

```
tblEmployee tbEmp = this.GetEmployeeRecordById(objUser.EmpId);
```

it queries your DB (Or at least I think it does, does it? Post the code here.). But your new user is not there yet. It will be added once you call `MYDB.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Hard to tell why, post `GetEmployeeRecordById` method please.

Comment: Does the query return a value or null after you add that second `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: I meant if you call `tblEmployee tbEmp = this.GetEmployeeRecordById(objUser.EmpId);` do you get a value or null from DB?

Comment: Hard to believe. `GetEmployeeRecordById` returns `tblEmployee` whereas `Where` returns `IEnumerable<tblEmployee>`. It should not compile.

Comment: sry my bad...missed out.SingleOrDefault at the end. Does it make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
public void Save(tblUser objUser)
{
 MYDB.AddTotblUsers(objUser);
 MYDB.SaveChanges(); 

 tblEmployee tbEmp = this.GetEmployeeRecordById(objUser.EmpId);
 if(tbEmp!=null)
   tbEmp.IsUser = true;

}
```

Obs: You don't have your objUser.EmpID before the insert at database. You need to insert and after it you can get your necessary ID.

if you need to make sure that both are saved or none, use TransactionScope to do it.

```
public void Save(tblUser objUser)
{
  using (TransactionScope ts= new TransactionScope())
  {    
    MYDB.AddTotblUsers(objUser);
    MYDB.SaveChanges(); 

    tblEmployee tbEmp = this.GetEmployeeRecordById(objUser.EmpId);
    if(tbEmp!=null)
    {  
      tbEmp.IsUser = true;
      MYDB.SaveChanges();
    }

    ts.complete();
  }
}
```

Regards.

Murphy

Comment: Tried. I guess I should put Savechanges() again after ..isuser=true;...right? did that. no luck

Comment: Are you getting some errors? If yes, can you please post them?

Comment: No Errors. I think, it is not necessary that tbluser has to save first before updating tblEmployee, because the EmployeeId in both the tasks is an already existing value and known before hand